# Editar widgets django

Tags: python, django, widget

Olá!
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Django.
Na página de cadastro do projeto aparece um SelectMultiple pro usuário selecionar os professores participantes.
Mas na página de detalhes eu só queria que aparecesse o nome dos professores que foram selecionados lá no cadastro.
Coloquei ao invés de SelectMultiple a widget TextInput, mas ao invés de aparecer o nome do professor, aparece apenas o ID. Eu queria que aparecesse o nome. Como faço?

Comment: Já experimentou o [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)? Veja também [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2556076/520779), ela mostra um exemplo de como usar o `Select` com uma lista de objetos de um modelo (um `SelectMultiple` deve funcionar igual, já que ele herda de `Select`).

Answer (score 3):

para conseguir o que você deseja, vá no model `Professor` e implemente o método `__str__` ou `__unicode__`. Algo como:

```
class Professor(Model):
    #...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome #assumindo que nome é o atributo do nome do professor.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome
```

O método `__str__` indica como um objeto daquela classe será exibido quando solicitado a sua string e o método `__unicode__` define como que um objeto daquela classe será exibido quando solicitado o seu unicode.

Comment: O método `__unicode__` só é necessário se estiver usando Python 2, pois o 3 usa strings unicode por padrão (mas é mais "garantido" ter os dois, podendo também um chamar o outro).